# Groovy is complaining about unexpected token: ->

Tags: groovy, mule

I've got the following Groovy script in Mule.

```
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.*
def expected = 
    getClass().getResourceAsStream('/samples/in/request.xml').text 

XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true)
def documentDiff = DiffBuilder
            .compare(expected)
            .withTest(message.getInboundProperty('webServiceRequest'))
            .withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals('EffectiveDate'))
            .build()
```

For some reason Groovy is complaining about "->"..

```
Script3.groovy: 10: unexpected token: -> @ line 10, column 34.
               .withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals(EffectiveDate))
```

I don't get it. I thought that was fine in Groovy? Am i missing something?

Comment: You might be using a version of Groovy which does not support Java 8's Lambda syntax. However, you can still use closures wherever a Lambda is expected, so `.withNodeFilter { node -> !node.getNodeName().equals('EffectiveDate') }` should do.

Comment: thanks. your comment here helped me a lot. This was more relevant than the suggested answer provided and led me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because here:

```
.withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals(EffectiveDate))
```

is lambda syntax from Java8 which currently is not supported by released version of Groovy (should be included in Groovy 3);

Instead of it use Groovy's clojures:

```
.withNodeFilter { //code here }
```

Answer (score 0):

in groovy it's not necessary to use command delimiter `;`

so new line could be considered as end of command if there is nothing mentioning contrary...

```
def documentDiff = DiffBuilder
            .compare(expected)
            .withTest(message.getInboundProperty('webServiceRequest'))
            .withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals('EffectiveDate'))
            .build()
```

should be done like this (dot at the end of previous string)

```
def documentDiff = DiffBuilder.
            compare(expected).
            withTest(message.getInboundProperty('webServiceRequest')).
            withNodeFilter(node -> !node.getNodeName().equals('EffectiveDate')).
            build()
```